# Algorithm complexity: Proof that $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor \geq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ and $n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1\geq \frac{n}{2}$, $\forall n\geq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

**Background / Context:**

I'm currently calculating the complexity of the following algorithm:

```
for j = 1 to n
    if j*j <= n
       for k = j to n
           f()
```

The function call `f()` is $\Theta(1)$. Through my research, with the following inequalities I can define the bounds for operation calls. The exercise is rather trivial, so I was rather interested in formally proving said inequalities and exploring a more general case:

Given $n\geq 2$:

1. $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor \geq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$
2. $n-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor+1\geq \frac{n}{2}$

Besides the proofs for these, they seem to be like there could be an intuitive explaination for me to grasp this better.

Also, is there a generalization of these statements for example changing the divisions by $2$ to divisions by $k$, $\sqrt{n}$ to $\sqrt[k]{n}$ and valid for $n\geq k$?

Comment: First provs the first one and then use the result for the second one.  In general $[a]>a-1$ (by definition).

Comment: For 1. note that $$
n \ge 4 \Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{4} \ge 1 \Rightarrow \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2} \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2} - 1 \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt n  - 1 \ge \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2} \Rightarrow \left\lfloor {\sqrt n } \right\rfloor  \ge \frac{{\sqrt n }}{2}
$$ and check the cases $n=2,3$ by hand. Intuitively this should be obvious for large $n$ since it basically states that $x>0$ is larger than $x/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to @Gary for a proof of statement 1. As for 2, it suffices to prove the stronger inequality:
$$n-\sqrt{n}+1\geq n/2$$
**Proof of 2:** Start with:
$$(\sqrt{n}-1)^2+1\geq 0$$
$$n-2\sqrt{n}+2\geq 0$$
$$\frac{n}2-\sqrt{n}+1\geq 0$$
$$n-\sqrt{n}+1\geq \frac n2$$
Proven as required.

Now consider the general case of the first statement:
$$\lfloor n^{1/k} \rfloor \geq \frac{n^{1/k} }{k}$$
**Proof of general case of 1:** It is possible to prove the more general case:
$$\lfloor n^{1/k} \rfloor \geq n^{1/k}-1 \geq \frac{n^{1/k} }{k}$$
$$n^{1/k}(k-1) \geq k$$
Now the general idea is to somehow use the definition of $e$ to help us. First of all we have to use $n>e>(1-1/k)^{-k}$ when $n\geq 3$, and then treat $n=2$ as a separate case:
$$n^{1/k}(k-1) \geq k$$
$$n^{1/k} \geq (1-1/k)^{-1}$$
$$n \geq (1-1/k)^{-k}$$
Now since $n\geq3>e>(1-1/k)^{-k}$, the $n\geq 3$ case is proven as required. As for the $n=2$ case, we have:
$$\lfloor 2^{1/k}\rfloor = 1 \geq 2/3\geq 2^{1/k}/3\geq 2^{1/k}/k$$
Also proven as required, and so we are done.

And finally, the general case of 2:
$$n-\lfloor n^{\frac{1}{k}}\rfloor+1\geq n/k$$
**Proof of general case of 2:** We prove the stronger inequality
$$n-n^{\frac{1}{k}}+1\geq n/k$$
$$(1-1/k)n+1\geq n^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
$$(1-1/k)n+1\geq n^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
Once again, we want to somehow use the definition of $e>(1-1/k)^{-k}$:
$$n^k\geq ne$$
Since $n\geq 3$ and $k \geq 2$. And so:
$$n^k\geq n(1-1/k)^{-k}$$
$$n\geq n^{1/k}(1-1/k)^{-1}$$
$$n(1-1/k)\geq n^{1/k}$$
$$n(1-1/k)+1 \geq n(1-1/k)\geq n^{1/k}$$
And so, proven as required, note that I had to handle the case $n=2$ separately as the above proof only does it for $n\geq 3$, which is why I had the proof at the start.

Comment: It's interesting that the margins for this inequality are quite large, so much so that the floor functions can be removed and the statement remains true. It also should be noted that the inequalities involving $e$ do come from calculus.